# Why I must use classname here in ANT?

Tags: java, ant, jar

```
 <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
          <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>
```

Why I cannot use something like

```
   <java jar="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true" >
          <classpath>
             <path refid="classpath"/>  
            <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>   
  </classpath> 
   </java>
```

I received the error like

```
 [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
 [java]     at oata.HelloWorld.(Unknown Source)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
```

Comment: Have you actually **tried** the second example? What was the result?

Comment: [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
     [java]     at oata.HelloWorld.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [`java` task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html), your second example should just work as expected (except that the `classpath` will be ignored).

**Edit:** The information you added to your question implies a few things:

1. the `.jar` file is found
2. it has the correct `Main-Class` entry in its manifest
3. your application requires log4j
4. it does **not** have a correct `Class-Path` entry pointing to a `log4j.jar` file

Basically the `java` ant task has the same requirements as using `java -jar` on the command line: if your `.jar` file doesn't correctly run using `java -jar myApp.jar` on the command line, then the `java` Ant task won't work like that either.

**Edit 2:** Whenever you invoke a `.jar` file directly in Java, then no further classpath can be specified in any way. That's true when you use `java -jar myApp.jar` and it's also true when you use the `java` Ant task with the `jar` attribute. That means that the `.jar` file itself must have a correct `Class-Path` entry.

Comment: @Hurda: that's implied by "as expected" ;-)

Comment: using the jar, the system reports error. Cannot find other jars.

Comment: @user: did you try to specify the `jar` location just as you did in the first example? (i.e. using `${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar`?)

Comment: it seems that classpath is ignored in the second usage

Comment: @user: yes, when invokind a `jar` directly then **only** the `Class-Path` entry in that `jar` files manifest is taken into account. You can't specify an additional classpath (that's true on the command line *and* in the ant task).

Answer (score 1):

Then how java is going to know which classname you are intend to run if yopu have more than one main class and you don't have entry in manifest. Use the classname attribute to run your main class.

Comment: I have Main-Class: oata.HelloWorld defined in the jar

Comment: if you are still facing issue executing the main class so please explicitly mention it in your classname attribute.

Comment: add the log4j.jar in your class path.It's trying to looks for the logger class.

Comment: even added classpath, it reports the same error. Modify the question